# You can't create a direct active relationship between A and B because that would introduce ambiguity

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling

- I want to activate the relationship between *Analyzers* and *Entries*
- A *Lab* has *Analyzers* (1-*)
- A *Lab* has *Entries* (1-*)
- An Analyzer ***might*** contain *Entries* (IdAnalyzer in Entries is nullable)
- So there could be *Entries* in a *Lab* but with no reference to any Analyzer
- I understand the problem is that both tables *Analyzers* and *Entries* are pointing to Labs
- I can see the redundancy comes from the database design, at the moment it was thought as quick and easy way to set these relationships

Can you explain this ambiguity?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand the problem is that both tables Analyzers and Entries are pointing to Labs

This isn't quite the right explanation.

The ambiguity arises because there are two distinct paths for `Labs` to filter `Entries`.

It already filters directly via

```
Labs[Id] 1-->* Entries[IdLab]
```

and if the relationship in question is activated, then also indirectly via

```
Labs[Id] 1-->* Analyzers[IdLab] 1-->* Entries[IdLab]
```

I'd recommend [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/bidirectional-relationships-and-ambiguity-in-dax/) for more insight into ambiguous relationships (even though it's largely about bidirectional relationships). [This article](http://cloudbi.com.au/how-to-manage-ambiguous-relationship-in-power-bi/) is worth a read too.

Comment: Solution in second article worked for me, thanks!